# LDAPStartTLSError: ('wrap socket error: [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:1108)',)

Tags: ssl, flask

Hy

I'm starting learning flask  but when I follow  this [documentation](https://pydigger.com/pypi/Flask-LDAPConn)

I receive this error... Strange that using ldapsearch everything is fine....

Using:

- Ubuntu Focal
- python3.8
- python3-flask                        1.1.1-2
- python3-flask-ldapconn               0.7.2-1
- python3-ldap3                        2.4.1-2
- python3-openssl                      19.0.0-1build1
- openssl                              1.1.1f-1ubuntu1
- slapd                                2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1

ldap.conf:

```
BASE    dc=contatogs,dc=com,dc=br
URI     ldap://zeus7.contatogs.com.br
SIZELIMIT       0
TIMELIMIT       0
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/cacert.pem
```

part of flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_ldapconn import LDAPConn

app = Flask(__name__)
ldap = LDAPConn(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'lihflhdlkfhlkfh'

import ssl
LDAP_SERVER = 'zeus7.contatogs.com.br'
LDAP_PORT = 389
LDAP_BINDDN = 'cn=admin,dc=contatogs,dc=com,dc=br'
LDAP_SECRET = 'adminldap'
LDAP_TIMEOUT = 0
LDAP_USE_TLS = True  # default
LDAP_REQUIRE_CERT = ssl.CERT_NONE  # default: CERT_REQUIRED
LDAP_CA_CERTS_FILE = '/etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/cacert.pem'
LDAP_CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY = '/etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/private/zeus7.contatogs.com.br.key.pem'
LDAP_CLIENT_CERT = '/etc/ssl/contatogs.com.br/newcerts/zeus7.contatogs.com.br.crt.pem'
```

When using ldapseach its ok:

```
ldapsearch -xLLLZZ -D cn=admin,dc=contatogs,dc=com,dc=br -w adminldap -H ldap://zeus7.contatogs.com.br | wc -l
```

Result: 5862

Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advanced

---

second round
Learning  a little more about ldap3 I could see same error (  https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_intro.html)

python3

Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16)

[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, Tls
> > >
> > > import ssl
> > >
> > > tls_configuration = Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
> > >
> > > server = Server('ipa.demo1.freeipa.org', use_ssl=True, tls=tls_configuration)
> > >
> > > conn = Connection(server)
> > >
> > > conn.open()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 56, in open
    BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 141, in open
    raise exception_history[0](https://pydigger.com/pypi/Flask-LDAPConn)(exception_history[0][2])
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: (LDAPSocketOpenError('socket ssl wrapping error: [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:1108)'),)

Maybe something about ssl/tls

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to get it working in the end? I have a pretty different configuration, but a working one. Not posting it as an answer at the moment because it's just a different configuration with Flask, and it's not STARTTLS but "regular" TLS1.3.

Comment: Thanks for interrest. I decide to use python3-ldap3 purely, as I couldn't   find a work around using flask_ldapconn. Maybe later I 'll return and test it again. In my case I always use StartTLS with openldap. Maybe I change it in future too...80)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the SSL config to accept older versions of TLS.

On Ubuntu edit /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf || In RHEL 8.1: /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config and edit the below:

```
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Note that this is a severe threat to security, but you can use it for testing and see if this helps.

ref:

https://takraw-s.medium.com/fix-errors-socket-ssl-wrapping-error-errno-104-connection-reset-by-peer-9c63c551cd7

https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues/385

I hope it helps!